# Фильтрация полей gridview для связанных таблиц

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Есть `GridView` в которой надо отобразить данные из связанной модели.

Это можно сделать двумя способами: через объявление публичного виртуального поля в модели и манипулирование наименованиями и значениями этих полей в `dataProvider` и `gridView`. Так же есть способ не указывать виртуальное поле, а просто в методе `search` прописать `$query->joinWith` с необходимой моделью, а в фильтр добавить условие поиска по `id`, например:

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = User::find();
    $query->joinWith('user');

    ...
    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', Settings::tableName() . '.name', $this->settings_id])
    ...
}
```

и в гриде можно будет манипулировать через атрибут `user.settings_id` без проблем.

Первый вариант выглядит очень костыльно (хоть и описан в гайдах фреймворка).
А второй вариант не пройдет если будет несколько связанных моделей, например три или четыре

Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Нет ли способа, чтобы не писать виртуальное поле, лишь для того, чтобы организовать по нему поиск и чтобы не оперировать чисто идентификатором вида `user_id`? Потому что оба способа выглядят просто абсолютными костылями. Зачем нужно было делать возможность обращаться к связанным моделям и полям в gridview, если фильтр пропадает и приходится городить такой странный огород?
2. Как можно сделать поиск и сортировку для связанных полей через одну или даже две, три таблицы не прибегая к виртуальным полям? Например `firm` → `subdepartment` → `user` → `settings` → `name`. Т.е. в `gridView` это будет как:

   ```
   [
       'attribute' => 'Наименование настройки',
       'value' => 'subdepartment.user.setttings.name',
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В смысле костыльно?! Создаете SerchModel которая наследуется от класса Modal, добавляете нужные поля для фильтра к примеру $settingName, пишете rulse для данного поля, джойните таблицу. В GridView в элемент (`'attribute' => 'settingName'`) вписываете значения атрибута фильтра, в 'value' как у вас или через `'content' => function ($model) { return $model->user->setttings->name }` связи можно оформлять также как и в вывод:

```
$query = User::find();
$query->joinWith('user.setttings'); // екземпляр User -> Setttings
$query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', Settings::tableName() . '.name', $this->settingName])
```

Так работает фильтр в фреймовому, у фреймворка хватает других костелен, так что 
на такую мелочь как фильтр можно закрыть глаза.

Comment: "В смысле костыльно?" --- в прямом смысле костыльно. Почему я должен указывать в классе одной сущности поля, которые к ней совершенно не относятся и более того они уже есть в другой сущности? Это нелогично и глупо и  приводит к дублированию информации. Это всё равно что я буду пачку мала хранить и в холодильнике и в квартире и в подъезде и в городе, в котором находится мой подъезд квартира и холодильник. ну не бред ли? Прямое нарушение архитектуры приложения где каждый должен быть ответственнен за своё и хранить то, что относится к нему. а то калькулятор печёт пироги - ну такое.

Comment: Это сьорч модель! ЭТО не сущность, все поля которые перечислены в ней используются только для фильтрации, и точка. Таких моделей можно и нужно создавать для разных ситуаций **UserSettingSearch extends Model** и  там уже перечень нужных полей для фильтрации. Если ваша сьорч модель наследуется от сущности, это уже костить!

Comment: Ну я её рассматриваю в равной степени с другими сущностями. Потому что она работает так или иначе с основной. Это всё равно, что я хочу найти свои данные секретные, но знаю в где и в какой базе ФСБ я это находится и в каком здании искать, вместо того, чтобы запросить их оттуда... Ну ладно. Костыль он и в африке костыль